# CREATE TABLE does not works to InnoDB, but works to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `peso_tec_dt_aj` (
  `idade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tecnico` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `obt` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `pad` decimal(4,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aves_peso` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_domingo` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_domingo_ajustada` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `peso_tec_dt_aj_idade_tecnico_index` (`idade`,`tecnico`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The query below works If I use the create with the statement ENGINE=MYSAM, but not If I use with engine InnoDB.

It works too if I dont make aggregations or if I remove the column field `data_domingo` (DATETIME) at the group by:

```
CREATE TABLE bucket_15.resultado as (
    select 
    peso_tec_dt_aj.idade,
    peso_tec_dt_aj.tecnico, 
    (
        ROUND(
            SUM(peso_tec_dt_aj.obt * peso_tec_dt_aj.aves_peso) /
            SUM(peso_tec_dt_aj.aves_peso), 3
            )
    ) as campo_computeado
    from bucket_15.peso_tec_dt_aj 
    group by 
    peso_tec_dt_aj.idade,
    peso_tec_dt_aj.tecnico,
    peso_tec_dt_aj.data_domingo
);
```

After run this query, MySQL doesn't show errors. The query without `create table` runs ok.

However, the query above is very simple. Why MySQL can't create a table with this columns and data?

MySQL Version: 5.7

Here is some screenshots to show you that with the same query, no results if engine is not MYISAM.

**FIRST IMAGE**: Run the query I will use on statement CREATE WITH SELECT using both engines: MYISAM and InnoDB.

[image]

**SECOND IMAGE**: Run the query without ENGINE=MYISAM. The result above is expected to be on the new table `resultado`, but it is not: without errors.

[image]

**THIRD IMAGE**: WITH ENGINE=MYISAM - table `resultado` is *magically* created

[image]

Comment: I tested this and it works without error using InnoDB. Please copy & paste the exact error message into your question above. When you ask a question on Stack Overflow about an error, always include the exact text of error message.

Comment: In the following script everything works as expect [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kFwq25KffTaXriMxZLUDd8/1).

Comment: `Errors` != `No errors`. Can you execute `CREATE TABLE` from MySQL Command Line?.

Comment: Why do you put the engine on the begin and not like whats usual on the end ?

Comment: @wchiquito - When I run at the command line, mysql gives show the error: `ERROR 1365 (22012): Division by 0`. It is strange that if I use the same query I get the results without the error described above, but if I use CREATE with SELECT, the error is presented by MySql. Even more strange is that if ENGINE is MYISAM, the error described by Mysql does not occur and the table is created normally.

Comment: See [5.1.8 Server SQL Modes :: ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero).

Comment: I don't see where you populated `resultado` in the Fiddle.

Comment: At the time of creating the fiddle, test data were not available, so the fiddle showed that it was not possible to reproduce the problem with the information posted.

Answer (score 1):

This create table works fine by my version 5.6.35 without any errors

```
CREATE TABLE `peso_tec_dt_aj` (
  `idade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tecnico` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `obt` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `pad` decimal(4,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aves_peso` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_domingo` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_domingo_ajustada` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `peso_tec_dt_aj_idade_tecnico_index` (`idade`,`tecnico`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE resultado as (
    select 
    peso_tec_dt_aj.idade,
    peso_tec_dt_aj.tecnico, 
    (
        ROUND(
            SUM(peso_tec_dt_aj.obt * peso_tec_dt_aj.aves_peso) /
            SUM(peso_tec_dt_aj.aves_peso), 3
            )
    ) as campo_computeado
    from bucket_15.peso_tec_dt_aj 
    group by 
    peso_tec_dt_aj.idade,
    peso_tec_dt_aj.tecnico,
    peso_tec_dt_aj.data_domingo
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

About the second query if it does not work MySQL should log the error int he terminal or to the log file.

In your second create query you had dot in the name. This was the reason why it did not work.

Comment: `Bucket_15.resultado` shouldn't be the problem. It will create the table `resultado` in schema or database `bucket_15`.

Comment: @wchiquito - `resultado` is not created. The final result is not the one it is expected!

Comment: Could you explain what you expect @calebeaires

Comment: @Noob - I edited the question and put screenshots to better understand the problem. Thanks for you reply.